# Specifying a dependency constraint in a cabal file

Tags: haskell, cabal

A bug in using the latest `attoparsec` with `hedis` needs `hedis` to be installed in the following way:

```
cabal install hedis --constraint=attoparsec==0.11.3.4
```

so that it doesn't use the latest version of `attoparsec`.

However, I don't know how to translate this into my project cabal file:

```
...

build-depends:       base >=4.7 && <4.8
                       , aeson >=0.8 && <0.9
                       , containers >=0.5 && <0.6
                       , zeromq4-haskell >=0.6 && <0.7
                       , bytestring >=0.10 && <0.11
                       , semigroups >=0.15 && <0.16
                       , exceptions >=0.6 && <0.7
                       , async
                       , hedis 
...
```

I would like the other packages to use the latest `attoparsec` but for `hedis` to use 0.11.3.4 only.

Comment: You can't, unfortunately. It's a limitation of cabal.